# Getting org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ssl, multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using apache http client library to post a maltipart request on some secure(https) server

> httpclient-4.5.13.jar, httpcore-4.4.13.jar, httpmime-4.4.1.jar

below is the sample code:

```
//creating HttpPost
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("some https://url");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

builder.addTextBody("channel_id", String.valueOf(pushNotificationRequest.getChannelId()));
        builder.addTextBody("input_type", pushNotificationRequest.getInputType());
        builder.addBinaryBody("csv_file", new ByteArrayInputStream(pushNotificationRequest.getCsvFile()), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "my-File.csv");
        
httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
```

//configuration for disabling the SSL

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
       .custom()
       .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).useProtocol("TLSv1.2").build())
       .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
       .build();
       
//exicuting the httppost
httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

but in above configuration I'm getting a wired issue when I freshly start the tomcat server (as above code in a part of web-app) and when this code is executed I'm able to connect to server which I'm posting the my request and after second attempt onwards I'm getting a exception
as:

> [ org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException ] null
> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

I'm not able to understand why it's working when server freshly started and getting exception after subsequent call.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The full stacktrace might contain useful information. See [httpclient logging](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) to enable tracing/debugging.